# How to check value are available in Enum using hibernate validator

Tags: java

How to check value are available in Enum?

For example I have below enum which contains below 2 data

```
public enum DeliveryMethodEnum {
    IMMEDIATE(1), 
    SCHEDULED(2);

    private Integer deliveryMethod;

    private DeliveryMethodEnum(Integer deliveryMethod) {
        this.deliveryMethod = deliveryMethod;
    }

    public Integer getDeliveryMethod() {
        return deliveryMethod;
    }
}

1. IMMEDIATE(1)
2. SCHEDULED(2)
```

I need to validate request parameter value which belongs to above enum. 
In request parameter we will pass 1/2/3..

If we pass 1 or 2 then it will pass because data are available in enum else it will failed.

Request param as below

```
{
    "deliveryMethod": 1
}
```

How to achieve the above things using hibernate validator?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator.

You will have to create an annotation that you can use on the parameter and then you need to implement the validator itself.

Pleaes check the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-simple

Comment: I need to validate value with enum constructor value.. will validate value with 1 or 2